# Including extra paths for cc_library without -isystem or symlinks

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I have a library, ported from a different build system with following structure:

```
.
└── foo
    ├── bar
    │   ├── a.h
    │   ├── b.h
    │   └── c.h
    └── something.cpp
```

In something.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include "c.h"
```

This structure is somehow enforced and can't be changed. There are also some code generators that generates additional code which reference mentioned files directly.

Then in BUILD file I can do:

```
cc_library(
    name = "foo",
    includes = ["bar"],             #1
    # strip_include_prefix = "bar", #2
    # copts = "-Ibar",              #3
    srcs = ["bar/a.h","bar/b.h","bar/c.h",something.cpp], #1 #3
    # srcs = ["something.cpp"],                 #2
    # hdrs = ["bar/a.h","bar/b.h","bar/c.h"],   #2
    ],
)
```

All of these solution have some issues.

- `includes` I will not get any warnings from the compilation because of the `-isystem` flag,
- `strip_include_prefix` symlinks with virtual includes are created what confuses IDEs and debuggers.
- `copts` could be possibly compiler specific and it's not transitive.

Finally I end up with the idea it would be useful to change bazel behaviour to use -`I` instead of -`isystem` flag for `includes`, is there any possibility to do that?
Maybe there's some better solution that address all those issues?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Finally in our project we created a new bazel rule based on cc_library implrmentation that handles includes with -I. I'm not happy with that solution but it works.

Comment: You could try to create a proxy cpp file via `expand_template( name = "proxy_something",  out = "foo/proxy_something.cpp", substitutions = { "a.h": "foo/bar/a.h", },  template = "foo/something.cpp",
)` from skylib and use the proxy_something everywhere. Hacky - but might work...